# Same ID "2015" already exists

Tags: magento2

i am getting error on magento as:

```
[2019-10-21 09:13:37] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Item (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor) with the same ID "2015" already exists. in /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php:406
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(304): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->addItem(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#1 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(1119): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->addItem(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor))
#2 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Collection/AbstractCollection.php(910): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->_loadEntities(false, false)
#3 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php(727): Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->load(false, false)
#4 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection->load(false, false)
#5 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor->___callPlugins('load', Array, Array)
#6 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection.php(831): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor->load()
#7 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->count()
#8 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/app/design/frontend/Mgs/adella/MGS_Mpanel/templates/widget/product_grid.phtml(24): count(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection\Interceptor))
#9 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home1/dtdemo/p...')
#10 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Block\Widget\ProductList\Interceptor), '/home1/dtdemo/p...', Array)
#11 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home1/dtdemo/p...')
#12 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/app/code/MGS/Mpanel/Block/Widget/ProductList.php(54): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#13 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Widget\ProductList->_toHtml()
#14 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/module-widget/Model/Template/Filter.php(117): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#15 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/module-widget/Model/Template/Filter.php(128): Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter->generateWidget(Array)
#16 [internal function]: Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter->widgetDirective(Array)
#17 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/Template.php(141): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#18 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Filter.php(1011): Magento\Framework\Filter\Template->filter('<div>\t<div id="...')
#19 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/module-cms/Block/Page.php(157): Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter->filter('<div>{{widget t...')
#20 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Cms\Block\Page->_toHtml()
#21 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#22 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('cms_page')
#23 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('cms_page')
#24 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(570): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('cms_page', false)
#25 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content', false)
#26 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#27 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(570): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', false)
#28 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main', false)
#29 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main')
#30 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(570): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main', false)
#31 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('columns', false)
#32 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('columns')
#33 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(570): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('columns', false)
#34 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.content', false)
#35 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.content')
#36 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(570): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.content', false)
#37 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#38 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#39 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(570): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#40 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#41 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#42 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(939): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root')
#43 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#44 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
#45 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(243): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#46 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(167): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#47 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#48 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#49 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('MGS\\Mpanel\\Bloc...', 'renderResult', Object(MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
#50 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#51 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#52 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('MGS\\Mpanel\\Bloc...', 'renderResult', Object(MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
#53 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#54 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#55 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/var/generation/MGS/Mpanel/Block/Framework/Page/Interceptor.php(39): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#56 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(140): MGS\Mpanel\Block\Framework\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#57 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#58 /home1/dtdemo/public_html/vdf/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#59 {main} [] []
```

Complete code of product_grid.phtml: https://pastebin.com/1RqSKE0U
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Duplicate entry in cataloginventory_stock_item is a common source for
>   this error. It is possible to search for an ID if you have one. To
>   find all duplicate product entity_ids, simply use the following SQL
>   statement:

```
SELECT * FROM cataloginventory_stock_item
WHERE product_id in (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM cataloginventory_stock_item
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING ( COUNT(product_id) > 1 )
)
```

**This will helps you out try This,
If its work approve the Answer
Thanks:)**

Comment: NO, there not showing any duplicate Ids

Comment: try Below solution!

Answer (score 0):

**To resolve this issue to to**

> lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php

```
public function addItem(Varien_Object $item)
    {
        $itemId = $this-&gt;_getItemId($item);

        if (!is_null($itemId)) {
            if (isset($this-&gt;_items[$itemId])) {
               // throw new Exception('Item ('.get_class($item).') with the same id "'.$item-&gt;getId().'" already exist');
            }
            $this-&gt;_items[$itemId] = $item;
        } else {
            $this-&gt;_addItem($item);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

**comment the throw exception line!**

Comment: Commenting this line will never solve issues, because that is only showing error

Answer (score 0):

You a *LEFT JOIN* in you collection which is causing the error.

All collections in Magento need to have unique items, where the uniqueness of the items is added by id of the entity (entity_id in you case).

I would suggest you add a breakpoint to frontend/Mgs/adella/MGS_Mpanel/templates/widget/product_grid.phtml(24) and retrieve the `(string)$collection->getSelect()` in order to see the actual query going to the database.

Product with id **2015** is returned multiple times (at least 2 times) in your collection

Comment: i have added complet code of product_grid.phtml: https://pastebin.com/1RqSKE0U

Comment: You can seed the select by adding on line 4 the following code:

`echo (string)$products->getSelect(); die;`